# Which component of the Linux (OS) stack handle BT speakers and smartwatches?

Tags: linux, kernel, architecture, development, peripherals

I reverse engineered Bluetooth interfaces of the [UE Boom 3](https://www.ultimateears.com/es-es/wireless-speakers/boom-3.html) speaker and [Pebble 2](https://www.cnet.com/reviews/pebble-2-review/) smartwatch, documented them and made Python scripts to use all the same features of their official iOS apps. I could make UIs etc. for my scripts, but I would like to add support for this more wide in Linux (OS). To which software/component of the Linux (OS) stack should I do a PR? To the kernel?

Comment: Not my area of expertise by any means, but perhaps approach the Bluez people?